# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at content delivery while implementing Tridion reference implementation

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, dxa

I m getting this error in core Log file while running Tridion reference implementation website.Stack trace of the error is here

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.tridion.meta.BinaryMetaFactory.getMetaByURL(BinaryMetaFactory.java:271)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:91)
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/ObjectNameNormalizer
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
        at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory.configureBundle(JPADAOFactory.java:76)
        at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:91)
        at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:65)
        at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:51)
        at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47)
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137)
        at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:113)
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104)
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/ObjectNameNormalizer
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.ObjectNameNormalizer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Detect premature EOF
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        ... 31 more
       at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
       at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
       at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
       at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
       at Com.Tridion.Meta.BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByURL(Int32 publicationId, String urlPath)
       at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl(Int32 publicationId, String urlPath)
       at DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013.TridionBinaryProvider.GetLastPublishedDateByUrl(String url)
       at Sdl.Web.DD4T.Statics.BinaryFileManager.ProcessUrl(String urlPath, Boolean cacheSinceLastRefresh, String physicalPath)`enter code here`
```

here is cd_storage.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
  <Global>
    <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
      <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
        <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb" />
      </Policy>
      <!-- The Features element specifies classes that add additional functionality to the cache. -->
      <Features>
        <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" />
      </Features>
    </ObjectCache>
    <Storages>
      <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
        <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
          <Property Name="serverName" Value="server" />
          <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
          <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
          <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
          <Property Name="password" Value="password" />
        </DataSource>
      </Storage>

    </Storages>
  </Global>
  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  </ItemTypes>  
</Configuration>
```

Here is all jar files in lib folder

activation.jar
   antlr.jar
   aopalliance.jar
   asm.jar
   cd_ambient.jar
   cd_broker.jar
   cd_cache.jar
   cd_core.jar
   cd_datalayer.jar
   cd_dynamic.jar
   cd_linking.jar
   cd_model.jar
   cd_odata.jar
   cd_odata_types.jar
   cd_preview_ambient.jar
   cd_preview_web.jar
   cd_session.jar
   cd_tcdl.jar
   cd_wai.jar
   cd_wrapper.jar
   commons-beanutils.jar
   commons-collections.jar
   commons-configuration.jar
   commons-dbcp.jar
   commons-digester.jar
   commons-fileupload.jar
   commons-io.jar
   commons-jexl.jar
   commons-lang.jar
   commons-pool.jar
   cwd_cartridge.jar
   cwd_engine.jar
   cwd_taglib.jar
   cwd_transformer.jar
   dom4j.jar
   easylicense.jar
   ehcache.jar
   guava.jar
   hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
   hibernate-core.jar
   hibernate-ehcache.jar
   hibernate-entitymanager.jar
   hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar
   hsqldb.jar
   jackson-core-asl.jar
   jackson-jaxrs.jar
   jackson-mapper-asl.jar
   jackson-xc.jar
   javassist.jar
   jaxb-api.jar
   jaxb-impl.jar
   jboss-logging.jar
   jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec.jar 
   jcl-over-slf4j.jar
   jdbcpool.jar
   jersey-core.jar
   jersey-json.jar
   jersey-server.jar
   jersey-servlet.jar
   jettison.jar
   json-smart.jar
   logback-classic.jar
   logback-core.jar
   patricia-trie.jar
   serializer.jar
   slf4j-api.jar
   snakeyaml.jar
   spring-aop.jar
   spring-asm.jar
   spring-beans.jar
   spring-context.jar
   spring-context-support.jar
   spring-core.jar
   spring-expression.jar
   spring-jdbc.jar
   spring-orm.jar
   spring-tx.jar
   sqljdbc4.jar
   stax-api.jar
   ua-parser.jar
   xalan.jar

After Debuging the application in visual studio i m getting System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null error at line 32 in Global.asax.cs file

```
Line 30:             SiteConfiguration.StaticFileManager = (IStaticFileManager)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaticFileManager));
Line 31:             SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper = (IMediaHelper)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IMediaHelper));
Line 32:             SiteConfiguration.Initialize(TridionConfig.PublicationMap);
Line 33:             RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
Line 34:             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

here is dynamic_config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd">
  <!-- The URLMappings define the relation between publication id's and domain names. It has optional attribute
            PathScanDepth which defines the deepest level what will be looked into the URI. The default value is 100.
            Values below than 1 will be considered 1.            
    -->
  <!-- <URLMappings PathScanDepth="20" > -->
  <URLMappings>
    <StaticMappings>
      <!-- The Publications element is a container for separate Publication elements. -->
      <Publications>
        <!-- The publication element allows you to specify Publication specific settings.
                 The Id indicates the id of the publication. This should be a number. -->
        <Publication Id="3">
          <!-- The Host element allows you to specify information about the site that
                        can be used to create URLs for Dynamic Links.
                        The following attributes are specified:
                           Domain    The domain of the website, for example www.tridion.com.
                           Port      The port of the website, for instance 8080.
                           Path      The path of the virtual directory of your website.
                           Protocol  The protocol used for the website. -->
          <Host Domain="localhost" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="" />
        </Publication>
      </Publications>
    </StaticMappings>
    <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl" />
  </URLMappings>
  <!-- This node configures the renderer used by the tcdl engine. You can define here custom renderer
    of the tcdl tags.
    -->
  <TCDLEngine>
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
  </TCDLEngine>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share some details of your `cd_storage_conf.xml`, since it looks like there is an issue with the configuration of your database in there.

Comment: ClassNotFoundException usual indicates just that; one or more jar files are missing. Double check what hibernate*.jar files are in the bin/lib folder of the web app...

Comment: i copied all jar files again which are provided in installation but still getting same error.

Comment: TridionConfig.PublicationMap is read from /bin/config/cd_dynamic_conf.xml, so for some reason this file is not found or incorrect. That would not be giving you the hibernate error though, so I suspect this is another problem

Comment: cd_dynamic_conf.xml file is correct and placed in website config directory.

Comment: Can you post it? There must be something wrong with it for the loading of the PublicationMap to fail (the code is fairly simple: https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/blob/master/web-application/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Config/TridionConfig.cs). If all else fails, you can get the whole source from Github and debug to the exact point where it breaks down

Comment: Your `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` also looks fine, there really appears to be something strange going on. Is a `BinaryData` created at all in your website root, or does it not even get there? 
I suggest you set the `log.level` of your `bin\config\logback.xml` to DEBUG, recycle the AppPool, delete the `cd_core.log` and request the homepage. Then perhaps you can upload the log generated then somewhere and link it here. The first 150 lines will give some insight on  your setup and after that it should start to load the binaries it needs for the site (where it appears to go wrong).

Comment: here is cd_core.log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7tOQoRKd9_0aUlmRzB3bmtKNU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems to me there are 2 separate problems, firstly the hibernate error - I have no idea why it cannot find this class if the hibernate jars are in the bin/lib folder of your site. Secondly, when you run the site in visual studio, it cannot pick up the cd_dynamic_conf.xml file - are you sure you copied this and other cd_* config files into the visual studio project bin/conf folder (and indeed the jars into bin/lib).

Comment: i m running visual studio project files from IIS.

Comment: with regards to the hibernate error, could you try to replace the `hibernate-core.jar` with the one from your working deployer? from the log it fails as soon as it is trying to load the storage factories, so sounds like something went wrong with that jar perhaps.

Comment: After replacing hibernate jar files from deployer previous error is not coming but i m getting  a error page. there is no error in cd_core.log file .here is error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7tOQoRKd9_0dHZtc20wVGJnRzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I suspect there is a mismatch in version now, are you absolutely sure your CMS, Deployer and Broker database are version 2013 SP1? Because it looks like the jars you copied were from a different version. Check a debug log from your Deployer for what version and build is mentioned there and look in the `TDS_DB_INFO` table of your Broker database to confirm it has 7.1.0.0 in the `DB_VERSION` field.

Comment: I manually copy all jar files from my tridion 2013 sp1 installer one by one and now website is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to some jar file mismatch i got these error .Manually copy jar files from 2013 sp1 installer i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it I think you missed step #5 in the documentation topic [Creating the Web application](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-E266C056-8AA6-4B7B-9700-F65F4795E002) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

In short, you forgot to install a JDBC driver for your database in the `bin\lib\` subfolder of the new Web application.

For example, when you are using a MS SQL server Content Delivery database, you should add the `sqljdbc4.jar` to the `bin\lib\` folder (copy it from one of your Content Delivery Web applications, like the HTTP Upload or OData).

After copying the required jar(s) for your JDBC driver, you will want to recycle te Application Pool of the site and then you can try if it works.

### UPDATE

The number of jars seem to match, and your `cd_storage_conf.xml` look sokay as well, assuming that you do have different property values in your actual one (pointing to your database server and with the correct username and password).

If all these things indeed check out to be correct, I would just delete the entire created webiste, and recreate it via the installation script, as it appears something strage is happening and figuring out what will most likely take a lot longer than to just recreate it through the installer script. Be sure to delete the website and its application pool and just let the installation script do its work again...

Comment: sqljdbc4.jar file is already there in lib folder.i m still getting this error.

Comment: Hi Bart i did the same as u said but no luck getting same error.

Comment: @AbdulQadir the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.ObjectNameNormalizer` error you are getting indicates an issue connecting to the Broker database, the class mentioned should be available in the `hibernate-core.jar` so I'm at a loss for what is going wrong. It could be something simple you missed like not having the right username password/connection details for your Broker database in your `cd_storage_conf.xml` or not having published the content, or there might be an issue accessing the files in your web application (are all DLLs unblocked and accessible for example).

Comment: i checked database info by creating an odbc connection on server and it is working and content also published in database i checked there are items in ITEMS table of broker database.dlls are also unblocked and accessible.Application identity pool user has full control on application directory.

Comment: Deployer is also configured on same server and i m using same storage config file for both deployer and website.deployer is working fine i m able to publish content in database.

Answer (score 0):

First do some basic validation like

1. Your cd license is valid.
2. Check if your website app pool has write permission to website's physical path.

If these are ok , then update your /bin/lib with one you got from your installation